# Computing a limit of sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

After applying l'Hopital rule twice, one sees that

$$ 
\lim_{n\to \infty} n a ~e^{-an} =0 \qquad \qquad (a\in [0,1]) .
$$ 
I would like to ask if someone can prove it using different way?
Bests.

Comment: Why twice ? Just apply it once : $\lim_{x\to\infty}xe^{-x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-x}=0$

Answer (score 4):

For any $x>0$,
$$ 0 < x e^{-x} = \frac{x}{\left(e^{x/2}\right)^2} < \frac{x}{\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}<\frac{4x}{1+x^2}=\frac{4}{x+\frac{1}{x}} $$
hence the claim follows by squeezing. You may also prove:
$$ \forall x\geq0,\qquad e^x \geq (1+x)\cdot\left(1+\frac{x^2}{3}\right). $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for another approach**: Let $b_n=an\cdot e^{-an}$, and let $a>0$. Then, $\forall n\ b_n>0$.

But $\lim_{n\to +\infty}{b_{n+1}\over b_n}=e^{-a}<1$, which means...